# Update does not add the correct values

Tags: sql-server

My select statement returns the ids from the tables I have joined correctly(393, starting at 92 and going up 484, its not a PK field, so some ids can be used more then once) there is a total of 550 rows I need to update, when I run the update it only adds the number 92 to the table for all 550 rows.

```
update movements set [location] = locaID.id FROM (
SELECT
      lo.id
  FROM [Harvest_Transactions] ht
  left join [Harvest_Master_Shift] hms on ht.Harvest_Master_id = hms.Harvest_Master_id
  left join [Greenhouse_Troughs] gt on ht.Trough = gt.Greenhouse_Trough_id 
  left join [batches] b on b.name = hms.Batch_id
  left join [phases] p on p.batch = b.id and p.[type] = 3
  left join #loc lo on lo.name = gt.Trough_No and lo.area = gt.SQM_per_Trough and lo.Bay_id = gt.Bay_id
  where ht.Number_of_Plants_Harvested != 0 and (hms.CreatedOn <= '2020-02-05 09:33:00.000' OR hms.CreatedOn is null )
 )locaID where product = 14
```

what am I missing so it updates with the correct values?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Or Postgres?

Comment: both I am running the update script in SQL Server but am pushing data to postgres , switching SQL to postgres

Comment: Its worth adding that to the question for clarify.

Comment: You are missing a SELECT just after = operator and before locaID

Comment: @Mohamad the select does not work here unless i want to turn it into another subquery

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag, as the syntax is clearly SQL Server only.

Comment: Because you have too many rows problem? So you can try SELECT DISTINCT. In ant case, the locaID subquery must return only one row or zero row for each ID having PRODUCT = 14.  Also you have to add product in the subquery SELECT, after lo.id.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression of your query is that only the rows with product = 14 in movements table will be updated with the single value coming from the subquery.

If you want to update the values based on another derived table, you need some way to link the rows together - i.e a JOIN between your table being updated and the table that holds the other data (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#OtherTables) )

What is the common column between movements and

```
SELECT
  lo.id
 FROM [Harvest_Transactions] ht
 left join [Harvest_Master_Shift] hms on ht.Harvest_Master_id = hms.Harvest_Master_id
 left join [Greenhouse_Troughs] gt on ht.Trough = gt.Greenhouse_Trough_id 
 left join [batches] b on b.name = hms.Batch_id
 left join [phases] p on p.batch = b.id and p.[type] = 3
 left join #loc lo on lo.name = gt.Trough_No and lo.area = gt.SQM_per_Trough and 
 lo.Bay_id = gt.Bay_id
 where ht.Number_of_Plants_Harvested != 0 and (hms.CreatedOn <= '2020-02-05 
 09:33:00.000' OR hms.CreatedOn is null )
```

The rough syntax shouldI think be

```
UPDATE movements
set [location] = locaID.id 
FROM movements
JOIN (
SELECT
  lo.id
 FROM [Harvest_Transactions] ht
 left join [Harvest_Master_Shift] hms on ht.Harvest_Master_id = hms.Harvest_Master_id
 left join [Greenhouse_Troughs] gt on ht.Trough = gt.Greenhouse_Trough_id 
 left join [batches] b on b.name = hms.Batch_id
 left join [phases] p on p.batch = b.id and p.[type] = 3
 left join #loc lo on lo.name = gt.Trough_No and lo.area = gt.SQM_per_Trough and 
 lo.Bay_id = gt.Bay_id
 where ht.Number_of_Plants_Harvested != 0 and (hms.CreatedOn <= '2020-02-05 
 09:33:00.000' OR hms.CreatedOn is null )
) locaID
ON movements.<some column> = locaID.<some column>
```

Comment: I have adjusted my query, instead of 92 filling in the spots its now null.

Comment: What have you adjusted?  Have you implemented a JOIN between movements and your derived table?